# Weibliche Entsprechung von "Heini"

Tags: usage, gender-neutrality

DWDS definiert "Heini" als *Schimpfwort für eine dumme, einfältige männliche Person bzw. jemanden, über den man sich geärgert hat oder den man nicht leiden mag.* Das Wort taucht oft auch als Suffix auf, z.B. in Provinzheini, Nadelstreifenheini, Versicherungsheini.

Gibt es hierzu eine analoge weibliche Bezeichnung oder ist der "Heini" eines der letzten männlichen Refugien?

Comment: Was genau meinst Du mit _passende weibliche Form_? Durch Beugung _"Heinin"_, oder semantisch, wie z.B. _"Trulla"_ (kann man auch sehr schön passend Zusammensetzen: _Provinztrulla_, _ChanelTrulla_, _TupperwareTrulla_, etc.)?

Comment: *Erna*, *Tante, Oma*, *Huhn*, *Henne*, also ein bischen Kreativität wenn ich bitten darf. Ansonsten unter "Etymologie" laufen lassen, dwds.de slricht sich dazu gar nicht aus.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Semantisch, keine gegenderte Form wie *Heinin*. Ich habe die Frage modifiziert.

Comment: Ich habe *Heini* bisher als eine Koseform des männlichen Vornames *Heinrich* verstanden. Daher ergibt es für mich keinen Sinn, daraus eine weibliche Form zu machen, schon gar nicht durch Markierung mit einem Suffix (die *Heinin* – die *Heinrichin*).

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Natürlich frage ich nicht danach, ob es das Wort "Heinin" gibt. Aber gibt es vielleicht eine Koseform eines weiblichen Vornamens, die dieselbe Konnotation (dumme, einfältige weibliche Person) hat? Oder andere Bezeichnungen, die das zum Ausdruck bringen?

Comment: *Du bist mir ja 'ne Trine.*

Comment: **_Trulla_** und **_Trine_** passen gut zu _Heini_, vielleicht noch **_Tuse_** und **_Uschi_**. Eine movierte, aber absolut unübliche Form wäre _Heinine_ bzw. (üblicher) über _Heinrich_ > _Hen(d)rik_ > _Hen(d)rike_ > _Rike_, aber da fehlt die semantische Konnotation komplett. Als eher einfältig gelten auch _Hein_ (Blöd) und _Hinnerk_/_Hinnak_. _Heinz_ ist hingegen diesbezüglich neutral.

Comment: @Crissov: Tuse soll aber Tusse sein, nicht?

Comment: Nee, _Tuse_ ist nicht so abwertend wie _Tusse_ und _Tussi_.

Comment: @Crissov *Tuse* habe ich noch nie gehört, aber das heißt ja nichts. [Hier](https://www.sprachnudel.de/woerterbuch/tuse) wird allerdings behauptet, dass "Tuse"  ein anderes Wort für Frau, Mädchen, Girl und noch etwas abwertender als "Tussi" gemeint ist. Also wie bei vielen Dingen vermutlich Ansichtssache ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In der Generation, die in den Ende 40ern, Anfang 50ern (in Mitteldeutschland) geboren ist, war öfter als vorwurfsvolle aber liebenswerte (und deswegen eigentlich ziemlich harmlose) Bezeichnung für Dummköpfe oder Tollpatsche entweder Heini oder **Liese** zu hören. Z.B.:

> Also das war mir vielleicht ein Heini!

und für Mädchen dann:

> Na, du bist mir 'ne Liese, was hast du denn wieder angestellt?!

(Die in den Kommentaren vorgeschlagenen weiblichen Begriffe erscheinen mir zu hart und zu negativ. "Trulla" ist schon beleidigend und bezeichnet sehr abwertend eine sehr blöde Person. Bei "Tussi" oder (noch abwertender) "Tusse" habe ich eher ein aufgedonnertes dummes Flittchen vor Augen. "Uschi" steht eher für ältere doofe Tantchen. "Trine" kommt "Liese" sehr nahe, aber ist auch sehr abwertend, da so eine eher die Analogie zu einer Trantute ist. Das alles kann natürlich mein persönliches Sprachgefühl sein, was durch Alter, Region und Idiolekt beeinflusst ist.)

Es gibt auch das berühmte Lied "Wenn der Topf aber nun ein Loch hat" mit lieber Heinrich, liebe Liese. Vielleicht deswegen das gute Gefühl für die passende Entsprechung von "Liese" zu "Heini".

Comment: "Liese" habe ich zwar noch nicht in dieser Bedeutung gehört, es überzeugt mich aber trotzdem. Eine Google-Suche nach "dumme Liese" liefert sehr viele Treffer. Danke auch für die Diskussion der anderen Vorschläge als Heini-Perndants, diese scheinen auch mir nicht treffsicher zu sein.

Comment: "*... aufgedonnertes dummes Flittchen ...*" ? [Laut Duden ist ein Flittchen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Flittchen) eine "*leichtlebige [junge] Frau, die häufig und mit verschiedenen Männern sexuelle Beziehungen hat*". Da sind wir aber sehr weit zurück in der Geschichte, oder? *Uschi* passt in meinen Augen spätestens seit Uschi von der Leyen sehr gut als weibliches Pendant zu Heini im Sinne von: einer, der irgendwie alles hingurkt, aber von nichts wirklich Ahnung hat.

Comment: @Olafant Im Sinne Deiner Uschi-Definition sind die meisten von uns in diesem Forum Uschis. Außer mir natürlich, ich  bin ein Heini.

Comment: @Olafant Und welcher unserer männlichen Polit-Stars ware dann keine "Uschi"?

Comment: @PaulFrost Alles Heinis! ;)

Comment: @Olafant Also Politheinis ;-) Und manche auch Provinzheinis ...

Answer (score 0):

Nö.

"Passend" ist durchaus eine unpassende Bezeichnung, solange *Trulla* o. ä. in der Regel als unangemessen gelten dürfte. Es ist also je nach Sprechersituation abzuwägen. Eine allgemeingültige Empfehlung scheidet daher aus.

Soweit *Trulla* nur für's weibliche Geschlecht gilt, plädiere ich dafür, *Heini* ebenso einseitig auszulegen. Schon der Artikel *der Heini* lässt es unpassend erscheinen.

Sowieso bietet sich die unpersönliche Mehrzahl *Heinis* an, die im Hochdeutschen jedoch unregulär erscheint und so vermuten lässt, die Einzahl sei in Analogie dazu, in einem etwaigen Missverständnis über die vielleicht ursprünglich anders gedachten Bezeichnung gebildet worden, wobei der Ursprung aber fraglich bleibt (*Hein Blöd*? *Highness* wie *Bündnis*? *Hain* ~ *Hagen* wie *Heide*? oder entfernt zu *-heit*?).

Ah jetzt, ja. Wie wärs mit *Provinz-Heidi*? Auch das wäre unfein zumindest allen Heidi genannten Personen gegenüber.

Comment: Ich muss zugeben: Provinz-Heidi hat was.

Comment: Vorderied bleibt unkorrigiert - vielleicht Vorderglied? Vorbild? Bitte noch mal selbst Korrektur lesen und frohes Neues, hier stellvertretend an alle.